# How to increase the salary of an employee based on the number of children in SQL ORACLE 10G?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, oracle10g

I have two tables: employee and dependent

**Structure**

*- Table employee*

```
Name        Null?       Type
EMPLOYEEID  NOT NULL    NUMBER(3)
LNAME       NOT NULL    VARCHAR2(15)
FNAME       NOT NULL    VARCHAR2(15)
POSITIONID              NUMBER(1)
SUPERVISOR              NUMBER(3)
HIREDATE                DATE
SALARY                  NUMBER(6)
COMMISSION              NUMBER(5)
DEPTID                  NUMBER(2)
QUALID                  NUMBER(1)
```

*- Table Dependent*

```
Name        Null?       Type
EMPLOYEEID  NOT NULL    NUMBER(3)
DEPENDENTID NOT NULL    NUMBER(1)
DEPDOB      NOT NULL    DATE
RELATION    NOT NULL    VARCHAR2(8)
```

**Data**

*- Table employee*

```
EMPLOYEEID  LNAME   FNAME   POSITIONID  SUPERVISOR  HIREDATE    SALARY  COMMISSION  DEPTID  QUALID
111         Smith   John    1                       15/04/60    265000  35000       10      1
246         Houston Larry   2           111         19/05/67    150000  10000       40      2
123         Roberts Sandi   2           111         02/12/91    75000               10      2
543         Dev     Derek   2           111         15/03/95    80000   20000       20      1
433         McCall  Alex    3           543         10/05/97    66500               20      4
135         Garner  Stanley 2           111         29/02/96    45000   5000        30      5
200         Shaw    Jinku   5           135         03/01/00    24500   3000        30
222         Chen    Sunny   4           123         15/08/99    35000               10      3
```

*- Table Dependent*

```
EMPLOYEEID  DEPENDENTID DEPDOB  RELATION
543            1        28/09/58    Spouse
543            2        14/10/88    Son
200            1        10/06/76    Spouse
222            1        04/02/75    Spouse
222            2        23/08/97    Son
222            3        10/07/99    Daughter
111            1        12/12/45    Spouse
```

And I have two employees: One employee has one child, and the other has two children. I got it with the following query:
**Query**

```
SELECT employee.employeid, lname, fname, salary, dependent.relation 
FROM employee INNER JOIN dependent
ON employee.employeeid = dependent.employeeid
WHERE dependent.relation = 'Daughter' OR dependent.relation = 'Son';
```

**Result**

```
EMPLOYEEID  LNAME   FNAME   SALARY  RELATION
543         Dev     Derek   80000   Son
222         Chen    Sunny   35000   Son
222         Chen    Sunny   35000   Daughter
```

And my homework is increase the salary $ 100 per child, and I tried with the following code:

```
UPDATE employee
SET SALARY = salary + 100
WHERE employee.employeeid IN (
SELECT employee.EMPLOYEEID FROM employee INNER JOIN dependent
ON employee.employeeid = dependent.employeeid
WHERE dependent.relation = 'Daughter' OR dependent.relation = 'Son' );
```

But, i don´t get the expect result. The employee "Chen" has two children, but his salary only increase once, no twice. Her final salary is $ 35100, no $ 35200.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Your update is adding 50 per child, not 100.  Also, the sub-select will return a list of employee ids that have children.  The outer select will only check if each employee id is in that list once.  (The list may have an ID multiple times, but the outer test is a single result only performed once per employee ID)

Comment: 100, no 50. Yes, I already corrected it!, but, the error persists

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I can't test on Oracle version 10, but this should work fine:</strike>
Well, apparently, it doesn't work in Oracle 10 (though it does work correctly in Oracle 12).  I added an alternative at the bottom of the post using `merge` that should work correctly.

```
update (
  select e.salary,
         d.childcnt * 100 as increase
    from employee e
    join (select d.employeeid, count(*) as childcnt
            from dependent d
           where d.relation in ('Son', 'Daughter')
           group by d.employeeid) d
      on d.employeeid = e.employeeid
) set salary = salary + increase
```

Here is another way of achieving the same thing using the `merge` command.  This should work correctly in Oracle 10:

```
merge into employee dest
using (
  select employeeid, 
         count(*) * 100 as increase
    from dependent d
   where relation in ('Son', 'Daughter')
   group by employeeid
) src
on (src.employeeid = dest.employeeid)
when matched then 
  update set dest.salary = dest.salary + src.increase
```

Comment: That's too bad.  This works ok in Oracle 12.  Version 10 probably wasn't smart enough to realize that the join would never return more than one row per `employee id`.